# How to accept client certificate permanently through starttls

Tags: asp.net, networking, c#-4.0, network-programming

select starttls  or  accept all secure connection ( which is available at your  end )

When sending mail  first time when   prompted  you want  accept this certificate choose accept it  permanently

I get this kind of requirement but i am not aware about anything starttls and all please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was mistaken it was starttls configuration with local email client like outlook we need to configure outlook through StartTLS,now my emails are sent out when i configure starttls in outlook with given credentials.